# Date sequence replication

Tags: r

I want to create a Date sequence as follows:

```
firstyear <- seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'),by='8 day',length=46)
```

then append the next year in the date sequence like 'first year', until the year 2017.

Lastly, the sequence contains  46*18 elements, shown visually like this:

```
2000-01-01
2000-01-09
...
2000-12-26
2001-01-01
...
2001-12-26
...
2017-12-26
```

How can I generate this Date sequence compactly?

Answer (score 1):

Using `sapply`

```
a=c(2000:2017)
yourlist=as.Date(sapply(a,function(x) seq(as.Date(paste0(as.character(x),'-01-01')),by='8 day',length=46)),origin='1970-01-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which will vary your date generation for you. Notice that I've transformed the output to a data.frame to preserve dates in "native" form.

```
yearSequence <- function(x) {
  data.frame(variable = seq(as.Date(sprintf('%s-01-01', x)), by = '8 day', length = 46))
}
```

You can apply the function to the years you want.

```
out <- sapply(2000:2017, FUN = yearSequence, simplify = FALSE)
```

Combine result as a data.frame.

```
result <- do.call(rbind, out)

> head(result)
    variable
1 2000-01-01
2 2000-01-09
3 2000-01-17
4 2000-01-25
5 2000-02-02
6 2000-02-10
> tail(result)
      variable
823 2017-11-17
824 2017-11-25
825 2017-12-03
826 2017-12-11
827 2017-12-19
828 2017-12-27
```